# How to write NDEF in host card emulation in flutter (for android)

Tags: android, flutter, nfc, ndef, hce

How do I write NDEF messages for host card emulation in flutter?
I´m writing a wallet app for passes (for android) and I need it to have NFC functionality (I can't use google smart tap)

The problem I´m having is that I tried to write with the library NFC_emulator (https://pub.dev/packages/nfc_emulator) but it did not work and I also cant write NDEF data in this library

What I want is to be able to send a string from an android phone to a scanner using NFC 4 payload (NDEF) in flutter
Can someone help me?

MANY THANKS

Comment: Having the same issues, that i dont find a way to emulate a host-based card with flutter. The package you mentioned was the only one i managed to get a reaction from a nfc reader that the app send something, but i cant send any data.